# Problem with magic_quotes_gpc in PHP symfony

Tags: symfony-1.4, php

I am using Symfony 1.4 and ORM as Propel, to create my project. Last time i have upgraded my server's PHP version from 5.2 to 5.3, from that time i am getting the error as

> PHP Deprecated:  Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PDO' not found in /usr/local/lib/php/symfony/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor/propel/util/PropelPDO.php on line 42
>
> PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  Module 'SQLite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Is there any thing i can do in code, or turn off 'magic_quotes_gpc' in php.ini?
please help!

Comment: Sounds like you have a PHP configuration issue that you need to take care of before you start working on any code. Check out ServerFault where those types of questions belong. StackOverflow is only for programming questions.

Comment: ok! sure i thought it might be regarding the Symfony issue!

Answer (score 1):

First error can be just silenced by disabling `E_DEPRECATED` in `error_reporting()`.

(Note: in general, silencing error messages is not a good way of dealing with errors - proper way of dealing with this error is to upgrade your scipts to version that supports PHP 5.3)

However you have four more much more serious errors, which I'm not really sure about.

Comment: is there any command to upgrade Symfony through command line, like it will take care of the latest version without effecting the whole project.

Comment: actually the symfony is upto date 1.4.8 which needs >=5.2.4, but i dont know why it is giving error! anyway thanks @Mchl

Comment: Maybe that's Propel or something else in your project. `in Unknown on line 0` is what bugs me. I've seen it before, but can't recall in what circumstances.